# How to delete grey borders

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

```java
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.HLayout;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.TreeGrid;

HLayout layout = new HLayout();
TreeGrid treeGrid = new TreeGrid();

layout.setMembersMargin(0);
layout.setBorder("0 none");
layout.setPaddingAsLayoutMargin(false);
layout.setLayoutMargin(0);
layout.setCanDragResize(false);
for (Canvas canvas : layout.getMembers()) {
  canvas.setMargin(0);
  canvas.setPadding(0);
  canvas.setBorder("0 none");
  canvas.setWidth("100%");
  canvas.setHeight("100%");
}
treeGrid.setMargin(0);
treeGrid.setBorder("0 none");
```

I have tried all these methods and border are still around the `treeGrid` which is in `layout`.
How to delete or tell SmartGWT to **not generate** these grey borders we can see between blue and green borders ? 
 
Or there is a component without these borders ?

[image: Illustrate borders problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not TreeGrid fault, proof : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_databinding_ondemand

Neither window fault, proof : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_windows_footer

I think, your border is being explicitly set somewhere.

Plus, you should take a look at the `Edge` property. Check for calls of `setEdgeSize(int)` or try to set edge size explicitly to `0`.

Comment: I have to make some changes in other developper' source code and I'm new in GWT. You were right, he set showEdge to TRUE... Thanks for this information. So I've just delete line `treeGrid.setShowEdges(true);`